# jQuery fileupload to upload both directories and files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I wanted to know if there is any way to use jQuery fileupload to upload both directories and files. I saw in the documentation that it is possible to upload directories with this input type

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple directory webkitdirectory mozdirectory>
```

But it says

> It is also possible to allow selecting a folder (**instead of files**) via the file input element by adding browser-vendor specific "directory" attributes

The "instead of files" part is pretty annoying for my usage. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uploader does not support folders and files, only folder, or only files. If you want to allow your users to upload a entire directory, using ZIP files could be nice.